# change a column datatype to timedateformat

Tags: python, pandas

n my data i have a col for date and this column consists of dates in the format of both that is 02/1/19 and 01-1-19

it is giving error if i am using this code data

`['Request date']=pd.to_date time(data['Request date'],format='%d-%b-%Y')`

```
data ['Request date']=pd.to_date time(data['Request date'],format='%d-%b-%Y')
```

`data['Requestdate']=pd.to_datetime(data['RequeDate'],format='%d/%b/%Y')`

how to use the both the formats in one single line of command.what should I DO?

python pandas

Comment: what if you specify no format at all?

Comment: Just use `pd.to_datetime(data['RequeDate'])` it will take care of the format.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `dayfirst=True` parameter, if both format have days in first place:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Request date' : ['02/1/19', '01-1-19'],

})

data['Request date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Request date'], dayfirst=True)
print (data)

  Request date
0   2019-01-02
1   2019-01-01
```

If need specify both formats create each dates separately with parameter `errors='coerce'` and jojn together by [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(data['Request date'],format='%d-%m-%y', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(data['Request date'],format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')

data['Request date'] = date1.combine_first(date2)
print (data)
  Request date
0   2019-01-02
1   2019-01-01
```

Comment: it is assigning date to month and month to date where - have been used

Comment: @DivyanshuThakur - Ok, what is expected output from `data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Request date' : ['02/1/19', '01-1-19'],

})` ?